# I want to open a Query in typescript?

Tags: typescript, azure-devops

```
window.open(TfsServer + svc.myTeamProject + "/_queries?path=" + _query + "&_a=query", "_blank")
```

[image]

I am using above line to open a query from vsts extension on click of a button.
The above line works while debugging.
This does not work when the extension is hosted on the server.
I get below error ,

> TF400893: Unable to contact the server. This is most likely caused by
>   a network error. Please check your connection and try again.

[image]

Comment: What's the type of extension? Is there error in console (F12 > Console) when click the button? Also check the request in Network (F12 > network). It is working fine for me with a hub extension.

Comment: it is a VSTS extension . This error is not  shown on console .It is directly shown on the TFS web page .

Comment: Navigation is from queries page to queries page in another tab on click of a work item.

Comment: Does it open in the new tab? What's the result if you access it directly? Does it require account? For me, it pass the authentication automatically with cached credential.

Comment: Yes this opens a new tab .If i access link directly it opens .But if i open the link using window.open() . It does not work .  It takes my credentials. but i am not able to open queries and backlog items

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue on other machine? You may share a sample project on the OneDrive.

Comment: Solved the issue by using                        VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.Navigation).then(function (navigationService: HostNavigationService) {
                            navigationService.openNewWindow(url); 
                        });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by using 
VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.Navigation).then(function (navigationService: HostNavigationService) { navigationService.openNewWindow(url); });

window.open() is useful when you are trying to open something in Hub.
Navigation service helps to open query window and backlog window.